# Break from a loop when a condition is true

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have this:

```
for(String s : names){ //names is an ArrayList of strings

  if( s.equals("bob") ){
       //do sth and then break from the loop
       break;
   }

}
```

When the condition inside the if is true, I would expect the for-loop to break. But it doesn't.. what I code wrong?

EDIT:

the problem was that I have an extra for loop in my code

```
 for( //a loop here){
      for(String s : names){ //names is an ArrayList of strings

            if( s.equals("bob") ){
            //do sth and then break from the loop
            break;
          }
       }
  }
```

that's why the inside `loop` was executing after the break...

Comment: Are you sure `names` contains a `"bob"` String?

Comment: And are you sure that it's all lowercase? Use `.equalsIgnoreCase` for case-insensitive string comparing

Comment: I vote to close as I had 2 for loops in my code..

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine, there is some data issue in your list or `difference of case in two strings` . Try using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` as suggested

It just prints `hi`, as soon as `bob` comes it breaks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("hi");
        names.add("bob");
        names.add("bye");

        for (String s : names) {
            if (s.equals("bob")) {
                System.out.println("breaking...");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
hi
breaking...
```

Comment: ok I see.. I found my error... I have 2 for loops  in my code.. thx for made me clear..